# Introducing the EWS Managed API!

Tags: exchange-2010

Does the system administrator need to install anything extra to get Managed EWS working for clients on Exchange 2010? At the moment I am getting problems just using AutoDiscover via the Managed API so i'm beginning to think the server has been configured incorrectly.

Has any administrator here had any experience with setting up Exchange 2010 to allow access via the Managed API?

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do anything extra. EWS is on by default, as Outlook (2007 and later), Communicator, Entourage, and several other programs use it by default. If AutoD is failing, I'd check to make sure that you have the correct internal and external URLs registered for the CAS; take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201695.aspx and verify that you've set everything properly.